# Titles of .txt files saved locally are loading in random order in tableview - how to force a specific order?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list of .txt files saved to Bundle and I list their titles to a tableview and load contents when row is clicked. I'm having a 2 fold issue.

**1.** The .txt files load randomly and in no particular order. I'm loading files like this right now:

```
func loadStories() {
    stories = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "txt", subdirectory: nil)!
}
```

Is there a way to force a particular order for the list?

**2.** I'm also having a loading lag of a few seconds the longer the .txt file is and it was suggested that I should maybe convert my files to .xml instead to speed this up. Is this a good solution?

I'm also using firebase for authentication but as I understand it, firebase would not be a faster solution for files that are read only and not going to be changed. What can I do to help speed up the load?

Answer (score 1):

**1. The .txt files load randomly and in no particular order. I'm loading files like this right now:**

I suppose `stories` is a collection (Dictionary / Array). Apply sorting in this array before reloading the `UITableView`

**2. I'm also having a loading lag of a few seconds the longer the .txt file is and it was suggested that I should maybe convert my files to .xml instead to speed this up. Is this a good solution?**

I think you are talking about the content of the files when showing details. You can add pagination in this case load part of the file (a few lines) show it. Then when further paged load further.

**Example : Sorting on string objects in swift array as asked in comment:a**

```
let months = ["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"]
var sortedArray = months.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

Comment: I load the stories in the initial vc and then they are var Stories = [URL] = [] in the tableview. I think this is a Struc. I know how to sort arrays by Int or alphabet, but i'm not sure how to set a sorting that is custom and not tied to a tangible value. How can I do that?

Comment: var Stories = [URL] --> its an array of URLs. you can call sorting method on this. Edited answer to sort array of string. Please let me know if you need something more. Also more part of code will be needed to help you in depth.